# RoboSpice and Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup, robospice

I have an application where I use Jsoup to get HTML file from the internet and parse it into POJOs. I use a custom Content Provider then to persist my POJOs into an SQLite database. It's a lot of code, and certain things are tricky to implement, caching especially (i.e. how to determine that my object is already in database, how to manage expiration, etc.). From looking over the internet I understood that RoboSpice might come to the rescue, since in handles caching transparently. However, I haven't found any example on how to plug in custom parser (my results are neither JSON nor XML, just pure HTML which I'm parsing with Jsoup currently). I'd therefore appreciate if you could point me to some related example.

Here's a more detailed description of what I'm doing. My app reads certain website to get the lists of certain entries. Those entries are calendar-based, and I'm requesting them month by month. Every month's request returns me a list of entries from that month. I want to make those requests cacheable and queryable, therefore I need a database backend, so that I can run custom SQL queries against it. Which RoboSpice configuration should I use, which extensions, and which code samples could I refer to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a good idea to use RoboSpice here, but the way you want to use is a bit out of its natural scope.

Usually people annotation a Pojo, let's say for Jackson, and they request a webservice, then the result is parsed via jackson and you get your Pojo. RoboSpice will simply reformat your pojo into json using jackson as parsing / formatting is a considered a bijection.

In your case, you will have to call your own ObjectPersister for your Pojo class and take care of its persistence format yourself. As you store your pojos into a database, the RoboSpice ormlite module may help but it is still experimental.

Have a look at the [sample of the ormlite module of RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-ormlite).